# Simple way to add data to columns

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I want to insert two separate datasets to columns in JavaFX TableView. Basically I have 2 LinkedLists with Strings and I want to put one list in one column and another to second one.

What is the easiest way to do this? Or is another JavaFX element better for this?

Only solutions I found so far were based on collections that were inserted into rows, which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would strongly recommend reorganizing your data, so that you have a class with two properties, one of which is an element from your first list, and the other of which is the corresponding element from your second list. Then you can make a list of objects of that class, and you are reduced to the usual case.

E.g. suppose you have

```
// your first list:
List<Integer> intList = ... ;
// your second list:
List<String> stringList = ... ;
```

Then define

```
public class MyDataType {
    private final int intValue ;
    private final String stringValue ;
    public MyDataType(int intValue, String stringValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue ;
        this.stringValue = stringValue ;
    }
    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue ;
    }
    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue ;
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
TableView<MyDataType> table = new TableView<>();
for (int i = 0; i < intList.size() && i < stringList.size(); i++) {
    table.getItems().add(new MyDataType(intList.get(i), stringList.get(i)));
}
```

and define the columns in the usual way.

If you really can't make that data transformation for some reason, then you can regard the type of the table as an integer, with the value for each row being the index into the two lists. Populate the table with the values `0, 1,...` up to the size of the lists. This looks like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewByColumns extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        List<Integer> intValues = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        List<String> stringValues = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");

        TableView<Integer> table = new TableView<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < intValues.size() && i < stringValues.size(); i++) {
            table.getItems().add(i);
        }

        TableColumn<Integer, Number> intColumn = new TableColumn<>("Value");
        intColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Integer rowIndex = cellData.getValue();
            return new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(intValues.get(rowIndex));
        });

        TableColumn<Integer, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Integer rowIndex = cellData.getValue();
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(stringValues.get(rowIndex));
        });

        table.getColumns().add(intColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(nameColumn);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(table), 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the Lists are of different size and I need the columns to contain whole list, so one column will be longer than the other one.

Comment: Surely you can modify the code for that case? I have a meeting now, but if it's really beyond you I will update when I get back...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, not very skilled in Lambda expressions in Java, but already got it. THX for help, marking your answer as solution.

Comment: if your lists are long thought, isn't it bad practice to keep calling "new" for every MyDataTypeObject... so if your lists are 1000 items each (same size) you'd call "new" 1000 times...I thought this was bad practice....

Comment: It is quite difficult to see how you would represent a list of 1000 objects without creating 1000 objects at some point. Why would this be bad practice?

Comment: I just remember from a school project we were reading from memory and I remember the teacher constantly saying to use "new" as little as possible but this is obviously different

Comment: @ponderingdev I know it's a year since you posted this, but just in case you haven't found out: object creation these days is a hell of a lot cheaper than it used to be. http://drmirror.net/2013/06/06/object-creation/

Comment: @James_D god bless you for the ReadOnlyStringWrapper thing, I've been looking for this for ages

Answer (score 1):

I found a JavaFX tutorial that appears to have solutions for taking collections and populating columns based on them, as well as having the table automatically updated as the collections change later, using an ObservableList.

http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/

Their code has a list of objects with two attributes, you would want to modify their code to draw from your two separate lists instead of accessing the two variables of their objects for the separate columns.

Comment: Isn't this just restating the question?

Comment: I don't believe it to be because they said they had only found solutions that populated data into rows instead of columns. This would be a solution to populate it into columns.

Comment: Your link is exactly the situation the OP described in the solution they found, with a list of objects, each of which represents a row. Your answer is just "Here is an example of the solution you found, modify it for your use case.", which just seems like a restatement of "How do I modify these kinds of solutions for this use case?".

Comment: I already visited the link before posting question. In there, they have a datatype which they're inserting as a whole into table. I have separate lists with different length.