# JavaFX Tableview: show column in a organised way

Tags: java, javafx

I have 3 columns in my table and I have  3 array list: categoryH,categoryS,categoryE. I want to put these values in each column.I am adding values in my table this way

```
categoryH.forEach((a)->products.add(new CategoryProduct(a,"","")));
categoryS.forEach((a)->products.add(new CategoryProduct("",a,"") ));
categoryE.forEach((a)->products.add(new CategoryProduct("","",a) ));
```

here CategoryProduct is a constructor. and I am getting my output like this

```
ab
bc
cd 
   ef
   gh 
   ij
      kl
      lm
      op
```

But I want to show data in the table like

```
ab ef kl
bc gh lm
cd ij op
```

Is there any other way to add data in my column from ArrayList so that I can show my data in the table in the desired way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to add data to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318713/simple-way-to-add-data-to-columns)

Comment: Just create your `CategoryProduct` instances with the appropriate values (i.e. each instance has one value from each list).

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot .